# Jackson XML to POJO list converting issue

Tags: xml, jackson, mapper

Could you please help me
I have a xml file with part

```
<time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none">
<layout-key>k-p24h-n7-1</layout-key>
<start-valid-time>2015-08-10T08:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<end-valid-time>2015-08-10T20:00:00-04:00</end-valid-time>
<start-valid-time>2015-08-11T08:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<end-valid-time>2015-08-11T20:00:00-04:00</end-valid-time>
<start-valid-time>2015-08-12T08:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<end-valid-time>2015-08-12T20:00:00-04:00</end-valid-time>
<start-valid-time>2015-08-13T08:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<end-valid-time>2015-08-13T20:00:00-04:00</end-valid-time>
<start-valid-time>2015-08-14T08:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<end-valid-time>2015-08-14T20:00:00-04:00</end-valid-time>
<start-valid-time>2015-08-15T08:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<end-valid-time>2015-08-15T20:00:00-04:00</end-valid-time>
<start-valid-time>2015-08-16T08:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<end-valid-time>2015-08-16T20:00:00-04:00</end-valid-time>
</time-layout>
```

And use bean to convert

```
public class TimeLayout {

    @JacksonXmlProperty( localName = "time-coordinate" , isAttribute = true)
    private String timecoordinate;

    @JacksonXmlProperty( localName = "summarization" , isAttribute = true)
    private String summarization;

    @JacksonXmlProperty( localName = "layout-key" , isAttribute = false)
    private String key;

    @JacksonXmlProperty( localName = "start-valid-time" , isAttribute = false)
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<String> startvalidtime;

    @JacksonXmlProperty( localName = "end-valid-time" , isAttribute = false)
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<String> endvalidtime;
```

But while parsing via XML Mapper from  Jackson library
We get only one pair of values  (the last one)

```
<start-valid-time>2015-08-16T08:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time>2015-08-16T20:00:00-04:00</end-valid-time>
```

Because each next  or  (from the very  beginning ) has its own context and set the value of the previous but not be added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to debug mapping problems is to start with POJO you have (construct instances programmatically), then serialize (write as XML), and see how structures differ. And from that, either modify annotations, Jackson XML module configuration, or, possibly POJO definitions.